# Error while using JDom to remove an element with specific attribute

Tags: java, jdom

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
  <data id="2-1">
    <ns>45</ns>
    <hfdi />
    <hfdv>0.26</hfdv>
  </data>
  <data id="2-3">
    <ns>49</ns>
    <hfdi />
    <hfdv>0.34</hfdv>
  </data>
</record>
```

I tried to remove the elements with specific attribute by using JDOM.

```
Document doc =null;
try{
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("config.xml"),StandardOpenOption.READ)
    doc = (Document)((new SAXBuilder()).build(is));
}catch(Exception ex){//do something}

for(Element elem : doc.getRootElement().getChildren("data")){
    if(elem.getAttribute("id").getValue().equals("2-3")){
        elem.detach();
    }
}

XMLOutputter xo = new XMLOutputter();
xo.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
try{
    OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("config.xml"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
    xo.output(doc, os);
}catch(Exception ex){//do something}
```

Then my XML become like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record>
  <data id="2-1">
    <ns>45</ns>
    <hfdi />
    <hfdv>0.26</hfdv>
  </data>
</record>
  "2-3">
    <ns>49</ns>
    <hfdi />
    <hfdv>0.34</hfdv>
  </data>
</record>
```

The element "2-3" is still there with no head!!!!

It seems that the element I want to delete does note be removed properly. How can I fix it?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What jdom version do you use? Could you please clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xing, I believe you must have a file open for writing, and then you overwrite the beginning of the file, but you don't truncate the file first. You end up with what you have there.

As for the detatch() vs. removeContent(...), the detatch will be faster, but is not what's causing your problem here.

Can you provide more detail on how you open and write to the file?

EDIT: excellent. Your Files.newOutputStream(....) method call needs to have the [TRUNCATE_EXISTING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#TRUNCATE_EXISTING) option set as well as the WRITE OPTION.

Comment: Hi, @rolfl. I've edited the post to show the clause related to the file. It not seems to be the reason of this problem.

Comment: Awesome! How it works? I'm still not very clear what the TRUNCATE_EXISTING did here though I've read the definition of it.

Comment: The Java7 NIO '2' extensions (Files, Paths, etc.) are very low-level concepts, they do exactly what they are told. You opened the file for WRITE, but you did not tell it to delete the old content first. The 'old' IO operators (new FileOutputStream(...) ) would do both those operations for you by default. In you case it is simply using a new API for file operations that is new to you, and is not as logical as you expect. On the other hand, a 'C' programmer will be thinking "well that's logical!"

Comment: Well, that's logical now. Thanks!